# XSLT identify XML tag element without attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a below scenario where in I want to process XML tags which do not contain any attributes.

```
<summary>1234</summary>
<summary type='google'>789</summary>
```

Is there some way I can write specific template match for both my elements.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="summary[@type='google']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="summary"/>
```

Second template process both  elements. I want second template to process only those  which do not have any attribute associated with it.

Comment: try something like this: `select="summary[count(@*) = 0]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following selects only summary elements without attributes.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="summary[not(@*)]"/>
```